# PHP CLI environment detection

Tags: php, server, environment-variables, command-line-interface, vhosts

I have a Linux server with a bunch of different websites on it. When I program websites, I will develop them locally and set APPLICATION_ENV to development. On my server, I have a staging subdomain setup which I set APPLICATION_ENV to staging. Lastly, if I end up hosting the production website, I can set APPLICATION_ENV to production. All of this works fine, but lately I have been running CLI tasks after every deployment. My command line scripts obviously can't do anything with the APPLICATION_ENV variable I have set up through Apache. I know that you can export a variable like so:

export APPLICATION_ENV="staging"

However, this would be setting it on my whole server, when I really only want to set it on the staging subdomain. Is there a way to contain these variables to a subdomain on my server?

Comment: When you set an environment variable in the CLI, it only affects that process and the processes it spawns, it doesn't affect the rest of the system.

Answer (score 1):

For title of your question:

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    echo 'This is CLI mode!' . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($argv);
}
```

For description:

I think you can set APPLICATION_ENV value with args or set it (in source code) as internal CLI APP ENV mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong to have environmental variables server wide, since you can set them for a specific user (or even session) only.

Anyway, probably the easiest way would be to pass the "env" as a parameter, e.g.: `cli.php --env=staging`

**Look how they solved it in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/artisan**

> Specifying The Configuration Environment
>
> You may specify the configuration environment that should be used
>   while running a command using the --env switch:
>
> `php artisan migrate --env=local`

**Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html**

`$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`